# preg_replace only works on a few

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, preg-replace

The code below is supposed to convert **bbcode** to **HTML** for my application, using the **Laravel** package.  I rebuilt the array to use my database instead.

https://github.com/golonka/BBCodeParser

The problem is that it converts a majority of the input, but not all.

A example is:

```
[code]html[/code] -> works
/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/s
```

---

```
[notice]html[/notice] -> doesn't work
/\[notice\](.*?)\[\/notice\]/s
```

Code to populate the array:

```
    $temps = DB::table('bbcodes')->get();

    foreach($temps as $temp) {
        $this->parsers[$temp->name] = [ 
            'pattern' => $temp->pattern,
            'replace' => $temp->replace,
            'content' => $temp->content
        ];
    }
    $this->enabledParsers = $this->parsers;
```

Comment: Improved wording and formatting

Comment: `preg_match('/\[notice\](.*?)\[\/notice\]/s', '[notice]html[/notice]')` works.